# MyFaces 2.1.8 Project on WebSphere 8.0.0.3

Tags: java, jsf, exception, websphere

I need to run my Java EE 6 project on WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.3.
The Server has Apache MyFaces 2.0 Support.

When I use the Server lib, the deployment works, but my application has some bugs.
Therefore I use Apache MyFaces 2.1.8. I put the api and impl in my WEB-INF/lib/ dir.
Also I configured my WAS parent_last and jsf-implementation SUNRI1.2.

When I deploy my project I get the following Exception:

```
[9/5/12 9:18:55:716 CEST] 00000012 config        I   Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_07-b03-FCS) for context '/mycontext'
[9/5/12 8:18:55:835 CEST] 00000009 DefaultFacesC I   Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
[9/5/12 8:18:57:815 CEST] 00000009 LogMetaInfUti I   Artifact 'myfaces-api' was found in version '2.1.8' from path 'file:MyProject.ear/Project.war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.8.jar'
[9/5/12 8:18:57:816 CEST] 00000009 LogMetaInfUti I   Artifact 'myfaces-impl' was found in version '2.1.8' from path 'file:MyProject.ear/Project.war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.1.8.jar'
[9/5/12 8:18:57:816 CEST] 00000009 AbstractFaces E   An error occured while initializing MyFaces: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory
                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.validateFactoryName(FactoryFinder.java:655)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.setFactory(FactoryFinder.java:301)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.setFactories(FacesConfigurator.java:498)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureFactories(FacesConfigurator.java:473)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:418)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:338)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1160)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:766)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2153)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)

[9/5/12 8:18:57:823 CEST] 00000009 StartupServle I   MyFaces already initialized
```

My faces-config is empty.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the WarClassloader parent last fixed the problem. Another way is shared lib.